# Quotient of powers of roots of unity minus 1 is an algebraic number?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I am reading algebraic number theory and got stuck by this little problem. Let $\zeta$ be the $p$-th root of unity, where $p$ is a prime number. Let $r,s$ be two integers that are coprime to $p$. Prove that $\frac{\zeta^r-1}{\zeta^s-1}\in O_F^{\times}$, where $O_F$ is the ring of algebraic integers in $F = \mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$.

How do I construct a polynomial with integer coefficients that has this fraction as one of its roots? Moreover, this fraction has to be a unit in $O_F$.

Comment: Hints: 1) it’s enough to show that it’s in $O_F$. 2) with Galois you may assume $s=1$.

Comment: Sorry, which result of Galois should I use? @Aphelli

Comment: Yes. Thank you so much! @DietrichBurde